# R highchart xAxis label only show first latter?

Tags: r, highcharts

I use R language, and highchart library.

This my code

```
library(highcharter)

resultData <- data.frame(name=c("frank"), caseEngNum=c(1))

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories=resultData$name) %>%
  hc_add_series(data=resultData$caseEngNum, name = "caseEngNum")  

hc
```

[image: result image]

xAxis label only show "f" letter, and then I add new row test.

```
library(highcharter)

resultData <- data.frame(name=c("frank", "tony"), caseEngNum=c(1, 2))

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories=resultData$name) %>%
  hc_add_series(data=resultData$caseEngNum, name = "caseEngNum")  

hc
```

[image: result image]

xAxis label show full name, It's work.

Why data frame only one row, that has xAxis label show problem ?

How do I resolve the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @frank, this is a know issue when the data have a length 1. You need to explicit use `list(resultData$caseEngNum)`, you can have more  details here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/173

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, I will use it. This is the solution for this issue. I change for         as.list(resultData$caseEngNum)
Thank you very much.